# What are CreateToken and StoreToken in SagePay Server V3.0?

Tags: opayo

We are upgrading our SagePay protocol from v2.23 to 3.0 to support surcharge fees. In v3.0 transaction registration post there are CreateToken and StoreToken which was not in the earlier version. What is the reason for create and store tokens? I went through the document but couldn't find a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is related to their token system, allowing you to store and send card details as a token.
If you don't use their token system you don't need to worry about it.

Sage Pay have destroyed their content recently so it's hard to find anything, here's a quick article on their token system - http://www.metakinetic.com/blog/2013/09/sage-pays-token-system-and-advancements-in-payment-gateways/

Answer (score 1):

The link provided in the above post links to advice by one of our Sage Pay Partners so take a look at it.

Token allows shoppers the option of storing their card details (as a token) to their account on the payment page during their first purchase instead of having to set it up manually afterwards. Single click purchases for repeat customers will become much simpler and quicker to set up.

To view the Token Guide go to [here](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document), scroll to the bottom of the screen and select the Download the Documents option within your preferred method of integration (server, server inframe, direct). Within the guide it explains creating and storing a token.

If this is a service you would like enabled on your Sage Pay account our New Business team are available 0900-1800 on 0845 111 4466. Prices for Token are available via [here](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/our-payment-solutions/online-payments/pricing). If you have any other questions, our 24/7 Support team can assist to on 0845 111 4455.

Sage Pay Support.

Comment: In the SagePay Server integration V3.0 guide StoreToken field mentioned as mandatory. Still it works without the field in TEST environment. Currently we don't have plans for Token system implementation. I'm worried why StoreToken is marked as mandatory.

Comment: StoreToken is mandatory for Sage Pay to know whether you want to store the token or not. StoreToken=0 (Do not store), , StoreToken=1 (store a token after three failed attempts or to be able to repeat against the token).

As long as the field 'Token=' is populated the StoreToken is mandatory. If there is no Token= field being passed the transaction will process without StoreToken field. 

With v2.23 protocol you could register a token before using the token. v3.00 token process has been improved so that can register the token whilst using the token.

Comment: The correct number for Sage Pay's support team is: 0845 111 4455. I can't correct it in the original post because of the minimum character change validation.